# How to pass value from <a> to click event via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pass value "**345**" by click on `<a>`

```
<a class="delete-button'" href="/Customer/Delete/345">Delete</a>
```

to this event.

How I can do it?

```
$(function () {
  function Delete(event) {
   myConfirm('Do you want to delete this record ?',
     function () {
        alert('You clicked OK'); // It should be 345 here
     },
     function () {
        alert('You clicked Cancel');
     },
     'Confirm Delete');
     return false;
}

 $('a.delete-button').click(Delete);

});
```

Thank you!

Comment: @ngen Sorry? What the framework is? It is MVC 3 project.

Comment: @ngen from the $ sign it looks like he's using jQuery

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear, I meant something along the lines of a PHP framework. It might already have a way to read 345 from the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it by putting the "345" in a data attribute on your link tag:

`<a class="delete-button" data-customer-id="345" href="/Customer/Delete/345">Delete</a>`

Then your delete function can reference it using the `.data()` method, like so:

```
function Delete(event) {
   var self = $(this);
   myConfirm('Do you want to delete this record ?',
     function () {
        alert('You clicked ' + self.data("customer-id")); // It should be 345 here
     },
     function () {
        alert('You clicked Cancel');
     },
     'Confirm Delete');
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use [$.attr();](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get Attributes of any element and use javascript replace() for replacing Strings..

```
$(function () {
  function Delete(id) {
   myConfirm('Do you want to delete this record ?',
     function () {
        // now you can use the variable "id" for 345...
        alert('You clicked OK'); // It should be 345 here
     },
     function () {
        alert('You clicked Cancel');
     },
     'Confirm Delete');
     return false;
  }

  $('a.delete-button').click(function(){
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     var id = href.replace('/Customer/Delete/', '');
     Delete(id);
  });
});
```

Another possibility would be data attributes:

```
<a class="delete-button'" href="/Customer/Delete/345" data-id="345">Delete</a>
```

the code above would be:

```
$(function () {
  function Delete(id) {
   myConfirm('Do you want to delete this record ?',
     function () {
        // now you can use the variable "id" for 345...
        alert('You clicked OK'); // It should be 345 here
     },
     function () {
        alert('You clicked Cancel');
     },
     'Confirm Delete');
     return false;
  }

  $('a.delete-button').click(function(){
     Delete($(this).data('id'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you check better your solution pls? Because it works for "OK" as well as for "Cancel"...

Comment: Cool... It should work but the last thing is how to add "data-id" to MVC3 Grid column? Could u help me please?                         grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "delete-button" }), style: "column-action")

Comment: I never used MVC3 Grid Column before.. You can try the first solution, thats working without data-id..

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Delete` function:

```
var recordId = this.href.match(/\d+$/)[0];
```

Comment: Sorry but your solution doesn't work at all. Could u explaint it better?

Comment: @Terminador: This gets the value of the `href` property and extracts the digits at the end of the string with a regular expression. If the URL is as you said, it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/QbzvJ/

Comment: @Terminador: Then your URLs might be different than the one you posted or you added the line at the wrong place.

Comment: @mVChr It should be like:  var link = $(this).attr('href');

Comment: Nope, it's a waste to wrap it in jQuery when you can access the attribute directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery `data()` function.  That way you can bind the data to the element, and access from there, instead of pulling it from the URL.